# Is it normal for a company to specify the name of the manager?

Tags: contracts

I am current employed as a bioinformatician.

My contract says: "you are employed as a [role],to report to and carry out the instructions of the supervisor [manager]. Based on this agreement, you will be given tasks from time to time".

My biggest complaint with my current manager is that he treats me like his private property. This text actually sounds like I AM his private property.

My question is: is this kind of role description normal/expected in UK? If it's not, would I be legitimately allowed to ask for something different, and how should it read?

Comment: Is the manager asking you to do anything that is not appropriate for [role]?

Comment: Is this a full time or contract position?   And that does not say you are his private property.  Given tasks and bought and sold as property are not the same.

Comment: Almost all job descriptions include "and other duties as assigned."  They're assigned by your manager. He *does* get to approve or veto any particular use of your working time.

Comment: Whether it is normal or not that is the contract you agreed to.  If you did not like the contract you probably should not have signed it.

Comment: Some managers are fantastic, others are terrible; most are somewhere in between.You haven't voiced your complaint other than "he treats me like his private property." Some managers do just that. That doesn't necessarily mean they are bad. If your manager is "bad", you can always vote with your feet. The line in your contract that assigns you to this manager is very standard.

Comment: "My biggest complaint with my current manager is that he treats me like his private property." <-- This should be your question and look to why this is and how to address it.  Questioning the text of your contract job description is the wrong approach IMO. Instead try to clarify what exactly your manager is doing that you find problematic, and seek to fix that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it normal for a company to specify the name of the manager?

It's not odd for a job description to name an individual manager.

But it makes no difference. If your manager "treats [you] like his private property", changing the job description won't change the way he treats you.

> would I be legitimately allowed to ask for something different

You can ask for something different, but realize that it's almost certainly a waste of time. Most likely your manager is in charge of your job description, so you'll have to ask him first.

Answer (score 0):

In the last two contracts I've signed this phrase was in it.

From my understanding the reason for this is that I work for a large (and wonderful) company with a **hierarchal structure**. I report to X, X reports to Y, Y reports to Z, Z reports to Alpha, Alpha reports to Beta, Beta reports to the CEO. Perhaps I missed a level. There are some advantages to this approach....for one my team's interactions are mainly internal and sideways; we can more readily focus on the work we need to do.